# Why is the number of unique users zero in my Facebook App Events console?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I just integrated Facebook SDK to my Android app and sent two custom events (logIn and logOut) from my device. Then I logged in and logged out two more times.

The number of events is 3 for logIn and 3 for logOut which is correct. But the column with **unique** events contains zeros.

Facebook SDK version: 4.20.0

**Code:**

```
class FacebookHelper {

    private AppEventsLogger mAppEventsLogger;

    Facebookhelper(Application application) {
        // application is the class extending Application
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(application);
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(application);
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.APP_EVENTS);
        mAppEventsLogger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(application);
    }

    public logEvent(String event) {
        mAppEventsLogger.logEvent(event);
    }

}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

... 
</application>
```

Comment: piece of your code will be helpful too

Comment: @Vivek, I added my code, but there's nothing special there. I just followed the quick start guide on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started